# Getting "missing braces around initializer" when initialize a linkedlist

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, warnings

I was implementing a linkedlist: Which has simple Struture and two helper functions, append to the end of llist and print the llist.

```
    typedef struct target{
      char my_target[65];
      int ID;
      struct target *next;
    }target_list;

    void append(target_list *head, char* new_data, int new_int){
  target_list *current = head;
  while (current -> next != NULL){
    current = current -> next;
  }
  current -> next = malloc(sizeof(target_list));
  strcpy(current -> next -> my_target,new_data);
  current -> next -> next = NULL;
  current -> next -> ID = new_int;
}

void print_list(target_list* head){
  target_list* current = head;
  while(current != NULL){
    printf("%d\n",current -> ID);
    printf("%s\n",current -> my_target);
    current = current -> next;
  }
}
    target_list head = {NULL}; 
     while(fgets (str , 1024 , f) > 0){
        char* num_args;
        char my_target[65];
        target_list head = {NULL};   //ERROR!
        int target_id = 0;
        int index_1,index_2;

        num_args = strtok(str," ");
        while (num_args != NULL)
        {
          if (num_args[0] != '\n'){
          append(&head,num_args,target_id);
          printf("the node now is %d\n",target_id);
          target_id++;
        }
          num_args = strtok(NULL," ");
        }
        print_list(&head);
        }
```

I was getting warning messages like:

```
original.c:283:5: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
     target_list head = {NULL}; 
     ^
original.c:283:5: warning: (near initialization for 'head.my_target') [-Wmissing-braces]
original.c:283:5: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
original.c:283:5: warning: (near initialization for 'head.my_target[0]') [enabled by default]
```

Any ideas? I've implemented llist before but have never seen msgs like this one.

Comment: Think about where this "*[...] makes integer from pointer [...]*"  might refer to.

Answer (score 1):

In statement `target_list head`, `head` is *normal struct variable* not *pointer variable*, you can't initialize with `NULL` which is `(void*)0`.

There are few things which you should take care, I just filtered out issues and listed.

- `head` should be `struct pointer` type, not normal struct variable.
  `target_list head = {NULL}` Should be `target_list *head = NULL;`
- second time no need to declare `head` again like `target_list head = {NULL};` it should be just `head = NULL;`
- Call `append()` like this `append(head,num_args,target_id);` and `print_list(head);`

Check `append()` functionality properly.